# WordPress Email different mx records bounce spoof

Tags: wordpress, email

I'm having trouble with a website that has it's domain abc.com though our email is hosted at xyz.com. When WordPress sends emails using user@abc.com(hosted with parent company at xyz.com) we get a bounce back for spoofing. Any help with which direction to look for a resolution is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What directions have you looked in so far? That would be useful to know, so we don't suggest things you've tried.

Comment: Most of what we done has been with code adjustments. Now we're thinking it may be an issue with the actual email mx records. ie. we were tested a contact form coded directly into a test page rather than the WP admin auto message using different emails.

Comment: One method is to route emails (being sent from wordpress) though a legitimate source. There is a a good way to use google for it: https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-send-email-in-wordpress-using-the-gmail-smtp-server/

Comment: We actually tried this method. I think maybe a better question is to understand what could be happeningin depth as it pertains to a differing host for our website(with wordpress) and with our email.